# Microsoft OLE DB driver not showing in ODBC manager after install

Tags: odbc, oledb, windows-server-2019

Can someone help me figure out why I can't see the OLE DB driver in the ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) after installation?

I have uninstalled, reinstalled, etc. I have followed guides referring to fixing registry entries. I have installed it as admin/non-admin. I have tried installing from different users.

This is the link for the drivers I am installing: [OLE DB Drivers for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image: OLE DB driver not showing in Data Source Administrator - Windows Server 2019]

Comment: The ODBC administrator is listing installed ODBC drivers. It doesn't display installed OLEDB drivers for the same reason that it doesn't show installed JDBC drivers.